# WCF Duplex service authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, wcf

I have been thinking about a way to implement this and I am not sure that what I have done is correct, because it surely sounds kinda dirty to me.

Basically what I have is a WCF duplex service which multiple clients subscribe to. My problem is the authentication. What I have done is I pass the username and password to the `Subscribe` method, then check those against the database and add the client's subscription to a `Dictionary<UserAccount,ICallback>`. Then(just for testing purposes so far) I have a timer which calls a method on each callback every 1 second.

All of this is working fine, with the exception that when I disconnect and connect the same client, the service crashes which I believe is a pretty trivial problem but I just haven't had much time to look into it. I am not sure this is the best way to handle authentication though. I do know about authentication using a custom UserNameValidator and a certificate with that, but last time I tried to do it, it took me a really long time and still couldn't get the client right for some reason, even though the service was working fine with a WCF service testing software(can't remember the name right now, but it was pretty decent IMO). Also I really don't want to have to deploy a certificate to every single client and purchasing a certificate is a big NO. The service is supposedly going to be working in LAN most of the time.

So here is the code:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class SchoolTestMakerService : ISchoolTestMakerService
    {
        Dictionary<UserAccount, ISchoolTestMakerCallbackContract> clients =
            new Dictionary<UserAccount, ISchoolTestMakerCallbackContract>();
        IHashGenerator hashGenerator = new SHA1Generator();
        UnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        Timer timer;
        int statusCode;
        public SchoolTestMakerService()
        {
            SchoolTestMakerDbInitializer dbInitializer = new SchoolTestMakerDbInitializer(hashGenerator);
            SchoolTestMakerDbContext context = new SchoolTestMakerDbContext(dbInitializer);
            unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context);

            timer = new Timer((s) => ChangeStatus("Status: " + statusCode++),null,0,1000);
        }
        public void Subscribe(string userName,string password)
        {
            string passwordHash = hashGenerator.GenerateHash(password);
            UserAccount userAccount = unitOfWork.Repository<UserAccount>().Get(x => x.Username == userName&&x.PasswordHash==passwordHash);
            if(!clients.ContainsKey(userAccount))
            {
                ISchoolTestMakerCallbackContract callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISchoolTestMakerCallbackContract>();
                clients.Add(userAccount, callback);
            }
        }

        public void Unsubscribe()
        {
            ISchoolTestMakerCallbackContract callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISchoolTestMakerCallbackContract>();
            clients.Remove(clients.First(x => x.Value == callback).Key);
        }

        private void ChangeStatus(string newStatus)
        {
            foreach(var client in clients)
            {
                client.Value.StatusChanged(newStatus);
            }
        }
    }


[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required,
        CallbackContract=typeof(ISchoolTestMakerCallbackContract))]
    public interface ISchoolTestMakerService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay=false,IsInitiating=true)]
        void Subscribe(string userName,string password);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsTerminating = true)]
        void Unsubscribe();
    }


public interface ISchoolTestMakerCallbackContract
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void StatusChanged(string newStatus);
    }
```

Client code:

```
using SchoolTestMaker.DataAccess;
using SchoolTestMaker.DataAccess.Utilities;
using SchoolTestMaker.DataAccess.Utilities.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;
using TestClient.SchoolTestMakerServiceProxy;

namespace TestClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userNameString = "UserName: ";
            string passwordString = "Password: ";
            Console.WriteLine(userNameString);
            Console.WriteLine(passwordString);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(userNameString.Length, 0);
            string userName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(passwordString.Length, 1);
            string password = Console.ReadLine();
            SchoolTestMakerCallback callback = new SchoolTestMakerCallback();
            SchoolTestMakerServiceClient client = new SchoolTestMakerServiceClient(new System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext(callback));
            client.Open();
            client.Subscribe("Pesho Daskala", "parola123");
            Console.Read();
            client.Unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}

public class SchoolTestMakerCallback:ISchoolTestMakerServiceCallback
    {
        public void StatusChanged(string newStatus)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(newStatus);
        }
    }
```

The client is basically a dead simple console application(just for testing purposes of course... haven't written the real client yet). The user account is also just a dummy for testing.

SHA1Generator and IHashGenerator:

```
public class SHA1Generator:IHashGenerator
    {
        public string GenerateHash(string input)
        {
            using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
            {
                var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
                var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);

                foreach (byte b in hash)
                {
                    sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
                }

                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

public interface IHashGenerator
    {
        string GenerateHash(string input);
    }
```

By the way, ignore the Session nonsense in the Service code. I forgot to remove it after switching to a single instance.(I am pretty sure it is pointless in that case and does literally nothing).

I'd really appreciate some help. I am pretty new to WCF but not to C# as a whole. I am sorry for the long question. I have tried to provide as much information as possible. If anything is missing please give me a chance to fix it before downvoting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problems**

- in `Subscribe()` you check, **without testing for null**, if this `UserAccount` is contained in the dictionary.
- in `Unsubscribe()` you use the callback to get the `Key` to call `Remove()` **without checking the success of the call**.

**Naming and style**

Your naming is good. You are using meaningful names and also use the correct casing.

The declaration part of your class variables of `SchoolTestMakerService` looks kind of ugly (sorry). You should consider to initialize `clients` inside the constructor.

**General**

I think the unsubscribe part is problematic, because you are using the callback which is the `Value` of a `KeyValuePair`to retrieve the `Key`.

I would add a class to the service having two properties, the useraccount and the callback like

```
class UserCallBack
{
    public UserAccount User { get; set; }
    public ISchoolTestMakerCallbackContract CallBack { get; set; }
}
```

which could be extended e.g by adding properties like `LastActive`, `TimeOut` and a `IsValid()` method.

Inside the `Subscribe()` method I would create a hash using the `username` and the `password hash`, which I would use as the key and the `UserCallBack` as the value of the dictionary.

This hash should be returned by the method and for each call of a service method be passed as parameter.

```
Dictionary<String, UserCallBack> clients = new Dictionary<String, UserCallBack>();

public string Subscribe(string userName,string password)
{
    string passwordHash = hashGenerator.GenerateHash(password);
    UserAccount userAccount = unitOfWork.Repository<UserAccount>().Get(x => x.Username == userName && x.PasswordHash == passwordHash);

    if (userAccount == null) { return String.Empty; }

    string key = CreateKeyHash(userName, passwordHash);
    if (!clients.ContainsKey(key))
    {
         ISchoolTestMakerCallbackContract callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISchoolTestMakerCallbackContract>();
         UserCallBack userCallBack = new UserCallBack() { userAccount, callback };
         clients.Add(key, userCallBack );
    }
    return key;
}

private String CreateKeyHash(string userName, string passwordHash)
{
    return hashGenerator.GenerateHash(userName + passwordHash);
}

public void Unsubscribe(string userKey)
{
    if (userKey == null) { return; }

    clients.Remove(userKey);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Those are all very good ideas and I especially like the HashKey approach. Do you think that sending username and password through an insecure connection is a bad idea? If yes what can I do about it while also avoiding the use of certificates?

Comment: bad idea, you could use some kind of pgp encryption like http://stackoverflow.com/a/787414/2655508